# Is there a mechanical button I can order/make that will sit on top of another hard-to-press button?

Tags: switch, woodworking, tools, appliances

My refrigerator's internal water dispenser is annoying to use because the button is hard to push. It's 1x1 inches and not comfortable to hold down. It is a physical button itself, so it has a travel distance of maybe 1/4". I've been searching for a big button that I could attach to the top of it so that it's easier to depress/hold while I'm dispensing water, and even better if that button was some kind of toggle so I didn't have to hold it down. I've tried googling for [mechanical|physical|spring|analog|etc] buttons but everything I find is an electrical button. I also think it would be a really cool little quality of life improvement for my family.

Comment: can you provide a model number of the appliance or a photo of the button? Is the top of the button flat, convex, or concave? Is it "ordinary" plastic (typically ABS) or metal? There are a number of DIY options for you depending on the answers. A photograph including the area around the button would be useful as well, in case a lever action solution is indicated.

Comment: A toggle or other similar switch would have the unfortunate and possibly catastrophic potential of completely flooding your house. That is why the OEM switches are *momentary contact*.

Comment: https://imgres.tailbase.com/rzdimg/prods/800/500195_3.jpg is the dispenser button in question. It's a rubber material and you can feel the button inside of it.

Comment: you could try installing a hinged lever ... hinge above the button ... lever hanging down from the hinge ... pressing end of lever activates the switch .... you could test the idea using a chopstick with something between the chopsick and the button

Answer (score 1):

I ended up working with a friend to 3d print a solution for this. It's a cam that can be turned to an "on" position. As it turns closer to "on", it has a mohawk that gradually increases in size until the button is pushed. It's mounted on 2 legs with ball bearings on them that allows the cam to rotate. The legs are command-stripped to the fridge wall, over the water button, so that the cam will turn it on when rotated.

Comment: I'd be interested in this solution, but I do not understand what's written. I don't know what a "mohawk" is, nor what is meant by "command-stripping."

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Command Strip™ is a brand name of removable adhesive tape. I think "mohawk" refers to the general shape of the cam that was 3D printed. I agree 100% that it would be better to have this [edit]ed into the answer.

Comment: @FreeMan That makes sense, thanks.